# Need to filter by order of a sub-set of xml nodes using xpath in a recursive xsl function

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a set of xml nodes with identical node names but one attribute that differentiate them, and an amount attribute:

```
<exampleNode typeOfnode="1" amount="100"/>
<exampleNode typeOfnode="1" amount="540"/>
<exampleNode typeOfnode="2" amount="200"/>
<exampleNode typeOfnode="2" amount="200"/>
<exampleNode typeOfnode="3" amount="10"/>
<exampleNode typeOfnode="3" amount="1"/>
<exampleNode typeOfnode="3" amount="110"/>
<exampleNode typeOfnode="3" amount="110"/>
<exampleNode typeOfnode="4" amount="110"/>
```

I'm using a recursive template to calculate the sum of the amounts, but only want to do that for a specific typeOfNode. Here is the code I'm using to call the template:

```
<xsl:call-template name="addition">
    <xsl:with-param name="currentValue">0</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="counter"><xsl:value-of select="count(//exampleNode[@typeOfnode= '1'])"/></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="typeOfnode">1</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="addition">
    <xsl:param name="currentValue"/>
    <xsl:param name="counter"/>
    <xsl:param name="typeOfNode"/>
    <xsl:variable name="amount" select="//exampleNode[@typeOfNode = '$typeOfnode' and $counter]/@amount"/>
    <xsl:variable name="recursiveValue" select="number($recursiveValue + $amount)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($counter - 1) > 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="addition">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentValue">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$recursiveValue"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="counter">
                    <xsl:value-of select="number($counter - 1)"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="agreementType">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$agreementType"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$recursiveValue"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Having debugged through wiTH XMLspy, the amount variable is not being set, and I assume it's because I'm screwing up the query. Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a quick answer, see the last code block. For some comments on the code, read from here.

1. How about fixing the recursive loop by using currentValue iso recursiveValue to seed the recursiveValue:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="recursiveValue" select="number($currentValue + $amount)"/>
   ```
2. There are some XSLT errors here, e.g. this does not look like it will work:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="amount" select="//exampleNode[@typeOfNode = '$typeOfnode' and $counter]/@amount"/>
   ```

   if you mean to say "amount is the @amount of the $counter-th /exampleNode with @typeOfNode=$typeofnode, this is not the way.

   - 'escaping' the variable will not work, it will compare to the literal value "$typeOfnode".
   - "and $counter" always evaluates to true, unless $counter is not set. Try "position()=$typeOfnode" but be aware that position will be the position of the current exampleNode in the entire set of exampleNode siblings. This could be fixed by using an intermediate variable where you 'copy' the exampleNodes that pass the filter, into which you test for the index using the $counter variable.
3. Your snippet

   ```
       <xsl:with-param name="agreementType">
         <xsl:value-of select="$agreementType"/>
       </xsl:with-param>
   ```

   is probably missing some confuscation, did you mean typeOfnode iso agreementType? :D

All of that aside, there are simpler solutions. for instance a quite direct:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(exampleNode[@typeOfnode='1']/@amount)"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I realised this on my way home and slapped myself in the face. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at details of your code, why don't you simply define a key

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="exampleNode" use="@typeOfNode"/>
```

and then to compute the sum you of nodes of type '1' you use e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k1', '1')/@amount)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you really, really want a recursive solution**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="recurse">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes_to_sum" select="//exampleNode[@typeOfnode='1']"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="0"/>
        </xsl:call-template> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="recurse">
        <xsl:param name="nodes_to_sum"/>
        <xsl:param name="sum"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count($nodes_to_sum)=0">
                <sum>
                <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>        
                </sum>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>

                <xsl:call-template name="recurse">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodes_to_sum" select="$nodes_to_sum[position()>1]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $nodes_to_sum[1]/@amount"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**About recursion**

In the first call we initialize the data; the whole set - already filtered - to calculate the sum of, and the initial sum (0).

In the recursive 'function' we first test for terminal condition, in our case, "nothing to add up anymore". If this is the case, return result...

...otherwise, that is, if there is more work to do, call the recursive part with a smaller todo-list and a higher accumulator, this guarantees the recursion will stop at some point.

but please see my other answer for a simpler solution...

Comment: This post was very helpful in general, and made me think about my recursive functions a bit more. I wish I could give rep, but my account is too noob :)

Comment: @user1428971 lol, thanks anyway (said the just-out-of-noob guy). just come back after you rep'ed up a bit :D
Recursion is really powerful, but sometimes overkill. I'm glad to hear you got a learning experience out of it.

Answer (score 0):

No recursion is necessary here!

**In fact, the wanted sum can be returned by a single, one-liner XPath expression**:

```
sum(/*/*[@typeOfnode = $pType]/@amount)
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pType" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*[@typeOfnode = $pType]/@amount)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment, wrapped into a single top element):

```
<t>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="1" amount="100"/>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="1" amount="540"/>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="2" amount="200"/>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="2" amount="200"/>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="3" amount="10"/>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="3" amount="1"/>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="3" amount="110"/>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="3" amount="110"/>
    <exampleNode typeOfnode="4" amount="110"/>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
231
```

Comment: Thanks for walking it through.